# Parse a argv in c to a command in unix

Tags: c, unix

I am new to unix and require some help.

I have another program call projectc which is an suid program located on another user call userb . userb has a directory pass that only has permission for write and read for its owner (userb)

I am trying to use the printf to do a command `printf(system("cat /home/userb/pass"))` through the argv argument.
I am able to do it in the c code `printf(system("cat /home/userb/pass"))` directly but doing it in the argv argument, i am unable to do it).
Is there anyway to parse the `argv[1]` parameter into a command?

this is my c program that I was trying to run in unix.

```
int main( int argc, char **argv){

    printf(argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You cannot 'call' a C function from a string unless you manually parse it. I'm surprised `printf(system(..` even did something for you - its return value is not a valid string and so `printf` may crash on that.

Answer (score 3):

```
printf(system("cat /home/userb/pass"))
```

The reason this seemed to work is because the spawned subprocess printed on the screen. The `printf` was not only unnecessary but actually a bug. The first parameter to `printf` is a string (`char*`), while the retrn value from `system`is an `int`.

A correct call would be:

```
int success = system("cat /home/userb/pass");
```

If `argv[1]` is the command you want to run you can just call:

```
int status = system(argv[1]);
```

You could then run your program like this:

```
myprogram "cat /home/userb/pass"
```

Note the double quotes - they ensure that the entire command is passed as a single parameter. Without the quotes it would be divided into two parameters.

And please turn up your compiler warning level. `printf(system("cat /home/userb/pass"))` should give some big warnings/errors when you compile.